# Very Slow upload speed | Ubuntu 16.04 | Dual-boot | Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e]

Tags: 16.04, networking, dual-boot, atheros, xps

After searching all through Google and Ask Ubuntu I couldn't find a fix to my problem: 
I have a Dell XPS 13 running Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 with Dual-boot and my internet download speed works just fine but my upload speed is *way slower* than my speed on Windows, and honestly I can't get any work done that way.

**Here are my Internet test results:**

```
$ curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/master/speedtest.py | python -
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from Bezeq International (79.176.94.28)...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by Partner (Tel Aviv) [1.56 km]: 30.989 ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 33.93 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed................................................................................................
Upload: 0.15 Mbit/s
```

**Results for: `sudo lshw -C net`:**

```
$ sudo lshw -C net
[sudo] password for liorscha: 
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3a:00.0
       logical name: wlp58s0
       version: 32
       serial: 9c:b6:d0:e6:d5:79
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.13.0-38-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00051-QCARMSWP-1 ip=10.0.0.15 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:286 memory:dc000000-dc1fffff
```

**Results for `iwlist wlan0 s`:**

```
wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning.`
```

**Results for `lsmod | grep ath10`:**

```
ath10k_pci             45056  0
ath10k_core           352256  1 ath10k_pci
ath                    28672  1 ath10k_core
mac80211              782336  1 ath10k_core
cfg80211              614400  3 mac80211,ath,ath10k_core
```

**These are the things I already tried:**

1. sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-firmware
2. Copying drivers from git repos to /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/*
3. Preferring IPV4 on IPV6
4. Encrypting with software instead of hardware

---

**EDIT**

[This](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_13_(9360)#Wireless) solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be effected by this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1670041). There are 68 posts of problems and suggestions. The latest one suggests to:

- Disable power saving
- Use latest kernel version - I'm using 4.14.34 and have had no problems on the 4.14 chain which is LTS (Long Term Support) for 6 years.

---

### May 4, 2019 update

Over a year ago, but after the original answer was posted, a bug fix came out. It happened during the kernel `4.16-rc5` release and the [source code change comments](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=36148c2bbfbe50c50206b6f61d072203c80161e0) state:

> Achieved throughput for different values of sk_pacing_shift (average
>   of 5 iterations of 10-sec netperf runs to a host on the other side of
>   the WiFi hop):
>
> - sk_pacing_shift 10: 43.21 Mbps (pre-patch)
> - sk_pacing_shift 9:  78.17 Mbps
> - sk_pacing_shift 8:  123.94 Mbps
> - sk_pacing_shift 7:  128.31 Mbps
>
> Latency for competing flows increases from ~3 ms to ~10 ms with this
>   change. This is about the same magnitude of queueing latency induced
>   by flows that are not originated on the WiFi device itself (and so are
>   not limited by TSQ).
>
> Signed-off-by: Toke Høiland-Jørgensen

Instinctively you think a kernel greater than `4.15` is required to get the bug fix. This is not so as the next section explains.

### Kernel 4.16-rc5 through Kernel 5.0 bug fixes are in `4.14.114` LTS

I'm still on kernel `4.14.xxx` LTS (Long Term Support) which has another 5 years of updates coming for it **including** the `4.16` patch above and recent kernel `5.0` bug fixes.

To prove the bug fix is there go to where my current kernel `4.14.114` is:

- https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.14.114/

It says:

> To obtain the source from which they are built fetch the commit below:
>
> ```
> git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel-test/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/mainline-crack v4.14.114
> ```

- Copy and paste the address into your web browser and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Google search comes up
- Click the first link
- A web page appears: https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel-test/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/mainline-crack/+ref/master
- Scroll to the bottom and select `All commits`
- The commit we are looking for is 10,000 messages back which is a lot of scrolling and searching.
- To speed the process up type `Adjust TSQ pacing shift` into the search field.
- An abbreviated result appears so click `Expand` and you will see:

[image: ubuntu kernel commits]

Comment: Thank you! I found the solution at the link you sent.
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_13_(9360)#Wireless 
This solved it eventually

Comment: Great. As you are new here, please click the check mark next to thus answer to help others searching on same issue.

Comment: I had to recompile the kernel and upgrade to 4.19.38.  Bounty added to reward you for pointing me in the right direction.  **0:-)**

Comment: @Fabby You are too kind. Thank you. I spent time improving the answer to highlight how the new bug fixes in `4.16-rc5` are rolled into the `4.14.xxx` LTS kernel chain.

Comment: I'm on 16.04 and the 4.19.38 custom kernel now.  Want me to leave it open until the last possible moment?

Comment: Others should know `4.19.xx` kernel chain is LTS (6 years of support). `4.19.38` was released May 2/19 quickly updated to `4.19.39` yesterday (May 4). It was updated to `4.19.40` an hour ago (May 5). As far as bounty goes I'll leave it up to you. I have pinged other answer poster to advise `4.16-rc5` patch is rolled into LTS kernels and `4.17` short term kernel (EOL now) doesn't have to be used.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm this issue is related to [bug #1670041](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1670041) as @WinEunuuchs2Unix posted.
FYI, my PCI-E wireless adapter is `TP-LINK TL-WDN4800`:

```
lspci -nn |grep -i wireless

Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0030] (rev 01)
```

> The low throughput with transmit TCP streams on ath10k should be fixed
>   with this mac80211 commit:
>
> mac80211: Adjust TSQ pacing shift
>
> https://git.kernel.org/linus/36148c2bbfbe50c50206b6f61d072203c80161e0
>
> Apparently v4.16-rc5 was the first release to have that commit.

Upgrading my kernel to 4.17 (former is 4.14 LTS) fixes this.

Comment: I noticed you posted a similar answer on a few websites. Commits from kernel `4.16` that deal with patches like **mac80211: Adjust TSQ pacing shift** are rolled into the `4.14.xxx` LTS kernel chain. I've updated my answer to confirm.