# XPS13 9370 wifi upload speed seems slow ? (ath10k, ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, download-speed

While playing with my wifi, I notice something:
if I download a file from my NAS to my XPS13, wifi speed seems good (like 20MB/s)
If I upload from laptop to NAS, it's reduce to ~1MB/s

I tested 2 hotspots (fast ones), at least much more than 1MB/s

Is there something I shall tune for this ?

edit:

I noticed this in my openwrt hotspot:

```
RX Rate / TX Rate

300.0 Mbit/s, 40MHz, VHT-MCS 7, VHT-NSS 2, Short GI
6.0 Mbit/s, 20MHz
```

edit2:
I found an interesting information here:
https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/ath10k
at very last line:
TX speeds are extremely poor on certain chips (QCA6174 is one). A patch solves the issue in most cases (source)

QCA6174 is what I have.
It seems to be a good point, but I have absolutly no idea how to use such patches...
help welcome !!

Comment: There was some discussion about the drivers here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025642/very-slow-upload-speed-ubuntu-16-04-dual-boot-qualcomm-atheros-qca6174-802