# WiFi randomly (or under load) disconnects on Ubuntu 18.04 with Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, network-manager, disconnect

With reference to [this topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030653/wifi-randomly-disconnected-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts?newreg=fac631c113ba4e7594569adf69777620):

1. I have changed WiFi powersave to off.
2. IPv6 support disabled.
3. I have reinstalled Linux firmware.

But nothing helped. The network still disconnects at random times

[EDIT]: OR under internet load! I have to close pages that download a lot of data, e.g. youtube. Then turn the wifi card on and off and internet comes back. If it does not close the charging websites or downloading, the connection will return for a second and then fall again. Even the Ubuntu update cannot be downloaded because the wifi disconnects

, reconnects after 4-5 minutes. I can't work like this.

No problem on Windows 10.
My card is:

```
06: 00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32).
```

EDIT: Here is my wireless-info.txt: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/7VkM8bwKW2/plain/

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: What kernel version is reported by `uname -r` I'm using same WiFi card with no problems on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/905363/ubuntu-16-04-cant-connect-to-home-wi-fi-with-killer-1535-qca6174/1025371#1025371

Comment: Not directly related but may be helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025642/very-slow-upload-speed-ubuntu-16-04-dual-boot-qualcomm-atheros-qca6174-802/1025654#1025654

Comment: A collection of bug reports on your WiFi card that my be a valuable resource: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1011764/unstable-wifi-connection-on-ubuntu-16-04/1011792#1011792

Comment: Have you confirmed that powersave is actually off? Eg. have you ran the command `ip devname get power_save` and confirmed it respond with `Power save: off`

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix kernel version `mateusz @ mateusz-Aspire-VN7-592G: ~ $ uname -r` `5.0.0-27-generic`

Comment: @KristopherIves `ip link 3: wlp6s0: <BROADCAST, MULTICAST, UP, LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000 link / ether b8: 86: 87: fd: 5e: bf brd ff: ff: ff: ff: ff: ff` `mateusz @ mateusz-Aspire-VN7-592G: ~ $ iw dev wlp6s0 get power_save Power save: off `

Comment: My: `iw dev wlp60s0 get power_save` returns `Power save: on`.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix  Do you suggest to return to 'on' settings and then the problem will be solved?

Comment: The difference is I'm using Long Term Support kernel: [4.14.140](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.14.140/) For installation see: [How to update kernel to the latest mainline version without any Distro-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade/885165#885165)

Comment: My powersave settings are setup here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/905363/ubuntu-16-04-cant-connect-to-home-wi-fi-with-killer-1535-qca6174/1025371#1025371

Comment: I think I have this same problem, I have to turn on and off the wifi settings in software to fix. I didn't realize it was related to load till i stumbled on this question but that may make sense `$ lspci | egrep Ath
6f:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)`. I am using Ubuntu 23.04 beta now but have had problem for a long time (Dell Precision 7540)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I solved it, at least it seems it works so far, by applying this workaround based on this [solution](https://support.killernetworking.com/knowledge-base/wi-fi-issues-with-1435-1535-1525-on-debian-ubuntu-and-arch/).

Here the workaround:

1. Replace the folder `/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0` with the
   corresponding from
   https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/tree/master/QCA6174/hw3.0
2. Rename `firmware-4.bin_WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1` to
   `firmware-6.bin`
3. Restart Ubuntu

Hope it helps.

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue for me

Comment: I'm a bit concerned by the fact that the files to download are over 5 years old, but there are newer files (2 months old) in a large sub-directory.  What are all the newer 4.4.1 firmware files for?

Answer (score 0):

I am affected by this problem as well.

I have a Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 wireless card. Every time I download a big file the wireless connection is lost.
It doesn't matter whether the download is done in the browser or with `snap`. Only a restart resolves the problem.
The problem happens in Fedora 33 and Kubuntu 20.10.

There is already a bug report at Launchpad: [Wifi drops, particularly under load](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1856372)

Comment: Linux is unrepeatable (every installation - a different effect), unpredictable and random...
Now I'm using the 20.04 release. Although there are still no officially drivers for the mentioned network card. Currently I have wifi connection with no problems. The problem is totally gone. Why was there a problem and was it gone? I HAVE NO IDEA.

Comment: @MatPa Curiously, I had the same problem on Windows 10. The problem occurred only in one specific wireless network. Other machines in that network did not have this problem.
So I now think that the problem is more related to the Qualcomm Atheros wireless card than to Linux.

Comment: Hmm possible. I used to have a similar problem (dell vostro 3460 computer - I don't remember what model of network card) with one specific wifi network on one particular router. So there can be a lot of reasons.